# Web based log4net viewer

Tags: log4net, viewer

We have an asp.net application that logs errors and warnings to xml files using log4net.

We have tried quite a few log4net viewers but didn't find any decent ones.

The latest one we have tried is log4net dashboard which is pretty good but doesn't do exactly what we need.

Our logs are saved in C:\MyApp\Logs[year][month]\log[date].xml

Is there any decent web based viewer that can allow us to view all the logs under C:\MyApp\Logs\

The viewer doesn't need to have a free license for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a post on their blog for this issue and how to work around it while a new build is dropped.

http://blog.reflectsoftware.com/2013/04/17/directorynotfoundexception/

I can confirm that creating this directory manually resolves the exception that is thrown.

Comment: I just tested their last install, they solved their issue. You no longer have create this missing directly manually. Apprently, their change was quit large but for the betterment, I was told.  How do you rate their product? Have you fully implemented this in your application(s)?  Any personal feedback would be great.

Comment: I've been using their product for the last 5 months and love it. We use log4net currently, so I started out with the log4net extension and now I've been migrated to ReflectInsight for all our logging needs. If I recall correctly they come out with updates regularly, and if you have a question...just contact their support. I once asked about a particular feature and whether it supported my needs. They responded promptly and then mentioned they implemented the feature as it made sense and made the product better. I am very impressed with their customer experience. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Maverick, thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated. It's a bit too early for me to say but from what I've seen so far, I'm really impressed with it. You're right, they are quite quick in responding to concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I've used l4ndash in the past and it is a good tool.

Have you tried changing this in the web.config?
This should load all files in that folder.

```
    <datasource name="XML Text file" Description="XML Text file (output from FilAppender or RollingFileAppender)">
        <provider type="L4NDashXmlTextFileProvider.XmlTextFileProvider" assembly="L4NDashXmlTextFileProvider, Version=2.4, Culture=neutral"/>
        <predefinedsearchfilter value="Filters\DefaultSearchFilters.xml"/>
        <providersettings>
            <filename value="C:\MyApp\Logs\*.*" /> 
            <SleepOnRename value="100"/>
        </providersettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply nimeshjm. I tried the setting you suggested but that didn't load any log files.